# ScrollView get back to top

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, touch-event, motionevent

So i have scrollView that has only one view on it (EditText), and i want to implement the

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
 View current_view = Processor.findViewGroupWithPoint(
            (int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY(), rmodel.layout.parent);
    if (current_view instanceof ScrollView) {


        switch( me.getAction() ){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d(TAG, " down");

            ((ScrollView) findViewById(111111)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d(TAG, " up");
((ScrollView) findViewById(111111)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            break;
        }
```

}

My problem is, when i scroll down, it works, but i have to hold my finger on the screen, as if i removed it, it will get back to top of the scrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it goes to the top of the scrollView when you let go because you tell it to.  you say

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    Log.d(TAG, " up");
    ((ScrollView) findViewById(111111)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
```

`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is used to detect when your finger is released, so when it does in this you tell it to go to the top with

```
((ScrollView) findViewById(111111)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
```

To fix this, all you really have to do is remove that line...

**EDIT:**

I wrote this up and it should work, might need some tweaks.

```
boolean bottom = false;
```

Basically here just create a boolean called bottom and set it to false ^^

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    Log.d(TAG, " down");

    if (bottom = false){
        ((ScrollView) findViewById(111111)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }else{
        ((ScrollView) findViewById(111111)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
    }
    break;
}
```

This is just seeing if the ScrollView is at the bottom or now... Hope it works!

Comment: true, when i implement the case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d(TAG, " down");

            ((ScrollView) findViewById(111111)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
 alone, it get me to the bottom, never back up, but i want to be able to get up too, when i move up, is there away to do the both?

Comment: You could use an if statement to detect if it is at the bottom or now.  I'll try to add an example but see if you can figure it out yourself!

Comment: Good answer. As a note to both of you, @A.AL, you shouldn't call `findViewById()` each time you want to reference that item. I'd recommend creating a class level variable, something like `private ScrollView mMyScrollView` and inside onCreate you can call `mMyScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(111111);` and in the rest of the code you can reference it like `mMyScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)`. This will not only make your code more readable, but improve performance by not digging through the view hierarchy multiple times.

Comment: @McAdam331, Thank you, i was just testing something when i wrote that code, but thank you i never know that calling findViewById() will effect the
performance , Thanks again